# How to use Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

It's been a while since I've needed to use FQL and I can now see that it has been depreciated and replaced with the Graph API. I've been trying to play around with the online tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer but can't seem to work out how to do something equivalent to an old query I use to run.

Is it possible with the API to search for a list of pages with between 1 million and 2 million likes (as an example). How would I do this?

Comment: No there is no API for that

Comment: so the previous functionality has been wiped entirely? FQL allowed querying a number of tables in the past. Surely they wouldn't just depreciate with no alternative.

Comment: a lot of stuff was removed without alternative. wizkid is right, there is no way to do that.